# Screenshot of scrollView returning null bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, screenshot

I am trying to take a screen shot of all the content of a scrollview(off page as well). The problem I am having is that when it get's to the line `Bitmap b = u.getDrawingCache();` an exception is thrown "nullPointerException". I can't seems to figure out what is causing this. This is the code I have:

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.btnSnap)
    {
        try
        {
            View u = findViewById(R.id.svContent);
            u.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            ScrollView z = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.svContent);
            int totalHeight = z.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
            int totalWidth = z.getChildAt(0).getWidth();
            u.layout(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);
            u.buildDrawingCache(true);
            Bitmap b = u.getDrawingCache();

            //Just so that I can get a quick preview of 
            //what the picture looks like
            ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivTest);
            img.setImageBitmap(b);

            //Save the picture
            File fileName = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/ArcFlash/SafetyCheckList1.png");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            handler.Log(ex.getMessage(), "onClick(SafetyCheckList.java)", context);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT** The problem seems to be at `u.layout(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight);`

Comment: I'm not aware that `getDrawingCache()` works anymore anyway. Have your `ScrollView` render to a `Bitmap`-backed `Canvas`.

Comment: it doesn't work in the sense that it doesn't capture everything including off screen content? Basically all I'm trying to do is store it as a png on the device so I can look at it later

Comment: "it doesn't work in the sense that it doesn't capture everything including off screen content?" -- I was under the impression that the use of hardware layers made the drawing cache approach no longer work in general.

Comment: In other implementations that I've tried it works and gets a bitmap. I was curious if any of the steps before getting to that line might be causing the null.